# 引用ブロックのデザインが変わりました

Tags: サポート, markdown

2020 年 2 月下旬から Meta Stack Exchange で議論されていた引用ブロックのデザイン変更が、どうも適用されたようです。

[Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/341401)

[Quote background has been changed from Yellow to White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/341401)

今まで黄色い背景色で表示されていたのが、左に灰色の線が入るのみとなりました。

[image: 新しい引用ブロックのスクリーンショットです]

これに伴って何かしら問題が生じていないか不安です。何か考えられる問題はあるでしょうか。